# Dell Inspiron 3451 upgrade 14 lts to 16lts fails

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, dell, inspiron

I would like to upgrade my Dell Inspiron 3451 from 14.04LTS to 16 ... every single time it fails. Error last time was "could not install sysv-rc" .. it continues installation but after all that displays new version but it fails upon reboot or restart. Afterwards have to reinstall factory version. Help. :)

Comment: What steps are you following to upgrade your system? Have you seen this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: I never use the upgrade process, I've had issues with it before. I always backup my data and then do a clean install. Can you just install a 16 version directly?

Comment: on the newbie side so fearful of doing a clean install due to drivers.

Comment: my steps are:  I get the notice for the update and I tell it yes to update. Takes its time to download. It downloads all and says it is done. It reboots and then crashes. The crash is so bad (and being a bit of newbie) that I am forced to reinstall 14